# How is this connection between Beta and Binomial possible?

Tags: r, distributions, bayesian, continuous-data, beta-distribution

I'm learning stats, and I've reasoned about this for many days and I'm losing sleep over it.

Say I have a binomial distribution `B(k; n, p)` simulating a hypothesis `p` value for some events:

```
B(14; 41, 0.5)
```

In R:

```r
dbinom(14, 41, 0.5) #=> 0.016
```

So in English, this could be said as "the probability of exactly 14 successes in a series of 41 fifty-fifty events is about 1.6%. OK, makes sense (a poor hypothesis).

Now, lets try iterating over different p values using R:

```r
p <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.01)
qplot(
  x = p,
  y = dbinom(14, 41, p)
)
```

This is clearly starting to form a shape of the probabilities for different probability values:

[image]

I understand this is not the "proper" way to do a beta distribution because of the fact that probability is continuous, and this graph needs to be integrated, it doesn't add up to 1, etc.

With that said... it *seems* the above chart *IS* perfectly "accurate", because each single value by itself is accurate.

Question 1: how IS the graph above "different" than a proper beta distribution in terms of what they describe in English?

- Incorrect beta distribution is saying (I think...) "For these 100 exact values, chart the probability (Y) that each probability (X) is correct"
- Correct beta distribution is saying (I think...) "For all possible values, chart the probability density (Y) that each probability (X) is correct"

Question 2: Are the charts related somehow? Like can they convert between them? It's clear from the incorrect chart I CAN compute a probability of a probability in a non-continuous way, yet in the second chart it appears there's no way I can do this unless I say something like `p > 0.49 & p < 0.51)`. How can both charts be "correct" (to my knowledge) yet in the continous one the probability of choosing that item is 0, and in the non-continous chart I can compute it just fine?

```r
qplot(
  x = p,
  y = dbeta(p, 14, 41)
)
```

[image]

Comment: From Wikipedia: "The binomial distribution and beta distribution are different views of the same model of repeated Bernoulli trials. The binomial distribution is the PMF of k successes given n independent events each with a probability p of success. Mathematically, when α = k + 1 and β = n − k + 1, the beta distribution and the binomial distribution are related by a factor of n + 1"

Comment: You are plotting the likelihood function $L(p|x)$, which is not a density in the parameter $p$.

Comment: The Beta density of $p$ is a Bayesian posterior distribution associated with the prior assumption that $p$ is Uniform distributed.

Comment: Your second graph is a duplicate of the first rather than what you get from your `dbeta(p, 14, 41)` code

Comment: ...and the code ```dbeta(p, 14, 41)``` uses the wrong parameter values in any case (which might explain why you did not show its plot).

Comment: @Ben Hmm... I thought the first argument was a "quantile" of everything "split up" (in this case the P split into groups of .01). what should it actually be?

Comment: Darn sorry... I didn't realize I put 41 instead of 27. Ugh...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function you have plotted is the [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics)) of a beta density function (i.e., it is a positive multiple of the beta density).  Since you have really just plotted the binomial likelihood function for a particular observed outcome, from a Bayesian perspective your plotted function is *proportionate* to the posterior density that emerges from using a uniform prior for $p$.  In Bayesian modelling terms, what you have illustrated here is that:

$$\underbrace{\text{Beta}(p | 15, 28)}_\text{Posterior} \ \propto \ \underbrace{\text{Bin}(14|41, p)}_\text{Likelihood} \times \underbrace{\text{U}(p|0,1)}_\text{Prior}.$$

(Note also that your last plot just appears to be a repetition of the first plot.  Your code for the beta distribution uses the wrong parameters; see the parameterisation of the [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) to see why the parameters should be as shown here.)  To plot the posterior density in this problem we can use the following `R` code:

```
#Plot posterior density
library(ggplot2)
XX <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.001)
DD <- dbeta(XX, shape1 = 15, shape2 = 28)
qplot(XX, DD, geom = 'line') + xlab('p') + ylab('Posterior Density')
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm... this is a great answer. Can you explain more what the proper code should be? I actually got this from offline, where they did this: `xs <- seq(0,1.0,by=0.01); qplot(xs,dbeta(xs,2*100,3*100),geom="line") +  theme_bw()`. it looked like this was manually making a sequence for all possible probabilities

Comment: In the present case you would use ```qplot(xs, dbeta(xs, shape1 = 15, shape2 = 28), geom = "line")``` instead.

Comment: OOOOOoooooo I didn't even notice that. I thought everyone was saying arg1 was wrong, I didn't even notice that I accidentally put 'all' instead of 'failures'. dang